# Spring JPA: Why is my list of users empty?

Tags: java, spring

H2  TABLE: `USERS`

```
 | USER_ID | USER_NAME | USER_PASSWORD | USER_RIGHTS |  
 -----------------------------------------------------
 |    1    |  rooter   |     123456    |    ROOT     |
```

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;
    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "user_password")
    private String userPassword;
    @Column(name = "user_rights")
    private String userRights;
    // equals() and toString()
}
```

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUserName(String userName);
    User findByUserId(Long id);
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UsersApi {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UsersApi(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public List<User> test(String name, Long id) {
        List<User> response = new LinkedList<>();
        response.add(userRepository.findByUserName(name));
        response.add(userRepository.findByUserId(id));
        return response;
    }
}
```

When I visit `/user/test?name=rooter&id=1` it will response with:

```json
[
    null,
    {
        "userId":1,
        "userName":"root",
        "userPassword":"123456",
        "userRights":"ROOTER"
    }
]
```

Why the method `findByUserName(String userName)` cannot find the data?

Comment: Why does query params say rooter? Try with root instead 

Comment: The user_name of it is "rooter"

Comment: I think @Aykhan is right, check the json response for `id`, userName is `root`

Comment: I think you messed up root and rooter - it is different in the table and the response.

Answer (score 0):

In the response array the username of the user with id 1 is root and the provided request parameter for finding a user by its username is rooter. So I would recommend you to check if the userName is root instead of rooter.